I have Dependency Track running on V4.12.1 is failing to create Child Project under an existing parent project when I try to upload SBOM
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UUID string too large
at java.base/java.util.UUID.fromString1(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.UUID.fromString(Unknown Source)alpine.persistence.AbstractAlpineQueryManager.getObjectByUuid(AbstractAlpineQueryManager.java:467)
I can see that Parent Project UUID is in correct format i.e. 0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F{12}]
Parent Project UUID is :                38b62b24-f823-4fa7-9a1e-e51a1569f6a1
Generated Child Project UUID is :       e56c80b1-374c-4ae0-a3ea-161faabde9a1
This Scenario only happends when I try to create child project along with SBOM Upload.
